# monitor files (à la tail -f) in an entire directory (even new ones)

Tags: logs, tail

I normally  watch many logs in a directory doing `tail -f directory/*`.
The problem is that a new log is created after that, it will not show in the screen (because `*` was expanded already).

Is there a way to monitor every file in a directory, even those that are created after the process has started?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can *tail* *multi*ple files with… [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

```
multitail -Q 1 'directory/*'
```

`-Q 1 PATTERN` means to check for new content in existing or new files matching *PATTERN* every 1 second. Lines from all files are shown in the same window, use `-q` instead of `-Q` to have separate windows.

Comment: I know this question was asked earlier in 2015 but I am running today in same issue. I have multiple dir and sub-dir and using this PATTERN ''logs/**/*' but though this watches for new files in a directory but does not work in terms of recursion. It looks for only in Grandchild directory of logs.

Comment: @Nish Indeed I don't think multitail implements any form of directory recursion.

Comment: This is great! It would be even more useful if I could use it more like `tail`-- without *any* of the ncurses control. I.e., so I could just scroll upwards like normally and see the prior contents. In my use case, I don't care which file the output is coming from. But I do want to easily scroll back upwards. I'm currently using a command `multitail  -d -Q 1 'directory/*'` but don't get any scrolling upwards.

Comment: looks like this is no longer maintained

Answer (score 15):

[`xtail`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xtail) is also an alternative. Its man page describes it as:

> Xtail monitors one or more files, and displays all data written to a
>   file since command invocation. It is very useful for monitoring
>   multiple logfiles simultaneously. If an entry given on the command
>   line is a directory, all files in that directory will be monitored,
>   including those created after the xtail invocation. If an entry given
>   on the command line doesn’t exist, xtail will watch for it and monitor
>   it once created. When switching files in the display, a banner showing
>   the pathname of the file is printed.
>
> An interrupt character (usually CTRL/C or DEL) will display a list of
>   the most recently modified files being watched. Send a quit signal
>   (usually CTRL/backslash) to stop xtail.

Comment: Link is broken, but I think is the same as: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/xtail.1.html

Answer (score 9):

Also you can watch directory with `watch`

```
watch -n0,1 "ls -lrt /directory/ | tail"
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: `watch` redraws the screen in the alternative buffer, with the first *x* lines of output from the command.  Across a number of files with no changes, if the earlier files do not change, the `tail` might render the same thing each time, so you get the appearance of no additional entries, as they are drawn in later files 'below' the bottom of the screen.  For a short file, though, this is fine...

Comment: This does not give a solution to the original problem. This just outputs (the last few lines of) a directory listing (repeatedly, always current - thanks to `watch`), instead of the latest lines of all files (including new ones) in that directory.

Comment: It took me a few tries to realize that "watch -n0,1" was either a typo or done in a different I18N context, and that "watch -n0.1" works in EN_US.

Answer (score 8):

No idea about a shell solution, but (assuming Linux<sup>`1`</sup>) [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) could be the way to go... [see this example imitating `tail -F`](https://github.com/manos/python-inotify-tail_example/blob/master/tail-F_inotify.py) (using [`pyinotify`](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki)), maybe it can be used as a basis for *following an entire directory*.

In general, `inotify` can monitor directories (citing [`man 7 inotify`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html))

> The following bits can be specified in mask
>          when calling inotify_add_watch(2) and may be returned in the mask field
>          returned by read(2):
>
> ```
> IN_ACCESS         File was accessed (read) (*).
> IN_ATTRIB         Metadata changed, e.g., permissions, timestamps,
>                     extended attributes, link count (since Linux 2.6.25),
>                     UID, GID, etc. (*).
> IN_CLOSE_WRITE    File opened for writing was closed (*).
> IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE  File not opened for writing was closed (*).
> IN_CREATE         File/directory created in watched directory (*).
> IN_DELETE         File/directory deleted from watched directory (*).
> IN_DELETE_SELF    Watched file/directory was itself deleted.
> IN_MODIFY         File was modified (*).
> IN_MOVE_SELF      Watched file/directory was itself moved.
> IN_MOVED_FROM     File moved out of watched directory (*).
> IN_MOVED_TO       File moved into watched directory (*).
> IN_OPEN           File was opened (*).
> ```
>
> When **monitoring a directory**, the events marked with an asterisk (*) above can
>          occur for files in the directory, in which case the name field in the returned
>          inotify_event structure identifies the name of the file within the directory.

(...and `pyinotify` closely follows theses options)

`1`: BSDs have a similar thing, `kqueue`.  Maybe a cross-platform solution is achievable using GIO ([Python bindings](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/)) as abstraction layer since it can, beside `inotify`, [also use `kqueue`](http://blog.netbsd.org/tnf/entry/gsoc_2011_roundup_add_kqueue)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a quick one that fulfils the need.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_PATTERN=$1
BASE_DIR=$(dirname $LOG_PATTERN* | head -1)

run_thread (){
    echo Running thread
    tail -F $LOG_PATTERN* &
    THREAD_PID=$!
}

# When someone decides to stop the script - killall children
cleanup () {
    pgrep -P $$ | xargs -i kill {}
    exit
}

trap cleanup SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <directory/pattern without * in the end>"
    exit 1
fi

# Wait for the directory to be created
if [ ! -d $BASE_DIR ] ; then
    echo DIR $BASE_DIR does not exist, waiting for it...
    while [ ! -d $BASE_DIR ] ; do
        sleep 2
    done
    echo DIR $BASE_DIR is now online
fi

# count current number of files
OLD_NUM_OF_FILES=$(ls -l $LOG_PATTERN* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

# Start Tailing
run_thread

while [ 1 ]; do
    # If files are added - retail
    NUM_FILES=$(ls -l $LOG_PATTERN* 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
    if [ $NUM_FILES -ne $OLD_NUM_OF_FILES ]; then
        OLD_NUM_OF_FILES=$NUM_FILES
        kill $THREAD_PID
        run_thread
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Actually, you can ommit the sleep 1 in the main loop, will be more snappy to get new files. But I don't like that kind of busy waits

Comment: Due to the `sleep` this is not a busy wait but soft on the CPU, just polling. One could change it to `sleep 0.2s` (GNU sleep) or whatever to make it faster if required.

Answer (score 3):

This works recursively.

It makes use of `inotify` (`apt-get install inotify-utils` on Debian) and just restarts the `tail` commands whenever new files/directories are discovered.

```
#!/bin/bash
logDir=/var/log/
while true; do
        ( find "$logDir" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tail --verbose --follow --lines=0 )&
        tailPid=$!
        inotifywait --recursive --quiet --event create --format=%w%f "$logDir" | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 tail --verbose
        kill $tailPid
done
```

My use case was redirecting all logs to `/dev/stderr` inside a docker container to have them show up in `docker-compose logs -f`.

Comment: This was the most useful answer for me. Inotify and the `inotifywait` command don't work on Sshfs paths, but then you can do `ssh HOST inotifywait ...`...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script that also uses `inotifywait`.  It watches for any new or changed file and runs `tail --verbose -n {NN}` on that file, which prints the filename and last `NN` lines.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
NLINES=75
function usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 {folder} [#lines]
  Monitor {folder} and execute 'tail -n [#lines]'
  for any new or modified files.
  Default [#lines] is $NLINES.
"
  exit 1
}
[[ ! -z $1 ]] || usage
[[ -d $1 ]] || {
  echo "ERROR: $1 is not a a folder."
  usage
}
[[ -z $2 ]] || {
  [[ $2 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && NLINES=$2 || {
    echo "ERROR: [#lines] must be an integer"
    usage
  }
}
inotifywait -m -e modify -e create --format=%w%f $1 | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 tail --verbose -n $NLINES
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a little different, but I had a need to monitor a directory and show the end of the most recent file continuously, on a (way back-level) system to which I could make no admin changes. That eliminated availability of inotify, multitail, or any new binaries, so a one-liner script is desirable. To do this, I modified @zombic's approach to the following:

```
watch -n5 "ls -tr $PWD | tail -1 | xargs -l tail -n $(( $LINES -2 ))"
```