# Is there a way to 'tail -f' a folder?

Tags: directory, tail, watch

I need a command that acts like `tail -f` (displays file changes in realtime), but it should display the new output for all files (even if the new file is created/added). I don't know what files will be there in the directory I need to listen, that's why I need it.

I found out that `tail -f folder_name/*` does what I want, but it doesn't work if I'll add a new file, it wouldn't display its changes.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a very similar [**question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39729/monitor-files-ala-tail-f-in-an-entire-directory-even-new-ones) was asked before.

**[monitor files (ala tail -f) in an entire directory (even new ones)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39729/monitor-files-ala-tail-f-in-an-entire-directory-even-new-ones)**

Essentially tail -f does not work as you expect because the * wildcard was expanded at execution time and tail isn't build to keep evaluating. You need to use a different app.

There are good solutions suggested in the answers to the previous question. The three I noticed are inotify, multitail, and xtail. It probably best to get more details about those in the other answers.

Comment: Good find, and welcome to U&L! The right thing to do in this case would be to flag this question as a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Reflex might be useful to you. It can watch a directory and run a command when files change. Written in Go.

https://github.com/cespare/reflex